# Customized Legend in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

Here I have a for loop to plot the content of my matrix.

Based on 'type' value I determine the plot object (ks,bO,rX)

```
for k = 1:length(data1)
    if(type(k)==1)
       h=plot(data1(k,1),data1(k,2),'ks');set(h,'linewidth',2);hold on;
    elseif(type(k) ==0)
            h=plot(data1(k,1),data1(k,2),'bO');set(h,'linewidth',2); hold on;
    else
            h=plot(data1(k,1),data1(k,2),'rX');set(h,'linewidth',2); hold on;
    end
end
```

I am little bit confused to find a way to put legend in my final figure, which shows my own explanation regarding each object(ks,bO,rX).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with a minimal set of data? I don't understand the condition `if type(k) ...` . Is `type` the built-in Matlab function?

Comment: It is just an array of integer which holds (-1,0,1). For example when it is 0 , capital 'O' will be plot. So In Legend I want to mention for example O represent negative values. But I couldn't find anyway to wring a string (as the description) beside O or X or the Square in legend.

Comment: What about `legend({'Type 1'; 'Type 0' ; 'Type -1'})` ?

Comment: It is not working, it just shows X beside type 0,type-1,type 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, MATLAB will see the output of this loop as not three plots but as many individual plotted points.  Even though some of the points are plotted with the same settings, it doesn't automatically recognise them as part of the same series. If you give it three legend entries, it will assign them to whatever the first three points plotted were.

The simplest way around this is to change the way you plot and use logical indexing, rather than a loop:

```
h=plot(data1(type==1,1),data1(type==1,2),'ks'); set(h,'linewidth',2); 
hold on;
h=plot(data1(type==0,1),data1(type==0,2),'bO'); set(h,'linewidth',2);
h=plot(data1(type==-1,1),data1(type==-1,2),'rX'); set(h,'linewidth',2);
```

Now we have only three plots, so giving `legend` the three  should give us the correct match between those plots (in the order they were plotted) and our labels:

```
legend({'Type 1'; 'Type 0' ; 'Type -1'})
```